run a Selenium test in headless mode with webgl support
I'm trying to run a selenium test in headless mode on a web page that is using WebGL (Cesium).  When performing driver.save_screenshot("..."), I'm seeing a banner in the middle of the screen that reads,

Error constructing CesiumWidget. Visit http://get.webgl.org to verify that your web browser and hardware support WebGL...

I've tried adding the following to my driver but so far the error message remains.
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--use-gl=swiftshader")

